# NoReverseMatch at /why is this occuring?

Tags: python, django

I had this error before but I couldn't fix it, so I moved back to previous git state. Now I have to fix this, why does this error keep happening? And what does this even mean? It's occuring from index.html {% url vote_for_post %} Here's my code, thanks in advance.

views.py

```
def index(request):

    categories = Category.objects.order_by('likes')
    latest_posts = list(Post.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:50])
    hot_posts = sorted(latest_posts, key=lambda x: x.hot(), reverse=True)
    controversial_topics = sorted(latest_posts, key=lambda x: x.controversy(), reverse=True)

    context_dict = {
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'categories': categories,
        'hot_posts': hot_posts,
        'controversial_topics':controversial_topics
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context_dict)

def vote_for_post(request, category_name, post_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, name=category_name)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, category=category)

    if request.POST['type'] == 'upvote':
        post.upvotes += 1
    if request.POST['type'] == 'downvote':
        post.downvotes += 1

    post.save()

    if request.POST['referer'] == 'index':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index'))
    if request.POST['referer'] == 'category':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:category', args=(category.name,)))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    #url(r'^add_post/', views.add_post, name='add_post'),
    url(r'^add_post/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-add'),
    url(r'^vote/$', views.vote_for_post, name='vote_for_post'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),


    url(r'^add_category/', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),

    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),

]
```

index.html

```
<div class="row placeholders">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="row">
                    {% if hot_posts %}
            {% for vote in hot_posts %}
                <article>
                        <div class="vote">
                            <form method="post" style="display: inline"
                                action="{% url vote_for_post %}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="upvote" name="type">
                                <input type="hidden" value="index_page" name="referer">
                                <button type="submit">+</button>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            </form>
                            <form method="post" style="display: inline"
                                action="{% url 'main:vote' vote.category.name vote.id %}">
                                <input type="hidden" value="downvote" name="type">
                                <input type="hidden" value="index_page" name="referer">
                                <button type="submit">-</button>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            </form>
                        </div>


                </article>
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>No topics are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add full traceback of your error? But basically the error happens because you are trying to use a url that's not defined. It could happen either in `{% url %}` statement in template or `reverse()` in views.py.

Comment: Also in your template the `action="{% url vote_for_post %}">` should be `action="{% url 'vote_for_post' %}">` with single quotes.

Comment: Did you include `main.urls` into your `project.urls`?

Comment: Yes I read the documentation and followed it just like you posted, but still get the same error. I get NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, "add_post", "vote" and "add_category" are ambiguous with your "slug" due to regex match.

> `url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),`
>
> `url(r'^vote/$', views.vote_for_post, name='vote_for_post'),`
>
> `url(r'^add_post/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-add'),`
>
> `url(r'^add_category/', views.add_category, name='add_category'),`

Try to give a better identifier for your urls.

e.g.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
url(r'^vote/post/$', views.vote_for_post, name='vote_for_post'),
url(r'^add/post/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-add'),
url(r'^add/category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
```

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

From the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url

```
{% url 'some-url-name' v1 v2 %}
```

In your code you should add `' '` to the name in the url template tag.

```
<form method="post" style="display: inline" action="{% url vote_for_post %}">
```

should be:

```
<form method="post" style="display: inline" action="{% url 'vote_for_post' %}">
```

Concerning the `NoReverseMatch at / u'main' is not a registered namespace.`

Remove the `'main:'` in your `(reverse('main:index'))` and `reverse('category', args=(category.name,))` in your views.py

```
if request.POST['referer'] == 'index':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    if request.POST['referer'] == 'category':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('category', args=(category.name,)))
```

Comment: Yes I read the documentation and followed it just like you posted, but still get the same error. I get NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] What does this mean?